# Seeking Middle Eastern Ambiances

Tags: library, atmosphere

Any tips on good Middle Eastern libraries. Specifically looking for unplaceable urban ambiances? Would settle for Brazilian shantytowns too. Ideally no identifiable languages.

This is the only one I've found so far:
http://www.tonsturm.com/Soundpacks/files/bff5b3f086d78d8ae90ac6c4899f1f7f-12.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I live in Dubai and have some ambience a but if you could give me an idea of exactly what you are looking for then I might be able to help. If I don't have any in my library I could go and get you specific sounds if you want.

There are modern and older areas of Dubai so lots of variety.

Let me know if I can help.

Comment: Thanks! OP here.Specifically I'm looking for Alleyways or deserted streets. Perhaps TVs or children behind walls from a alley perspective although I can always incorporate that myself. Ideally no easily recognizable arabic language.

Comment: *tried emailing you but it bounced. You can contact me here: http://www.jeremyb.com/contact/

Answer (score 1):

That was actually the one I was going to suggest.  You may find some luck in the DigiFX or BBC sets.  The DIGI A set has some great material for foreign, especially the traffic recordings. As for any other small botique library sets along those lines of what you want for Middle East, I'm not aware of anything else out there aside from the Tonsturm set.  I'm all ears if someone else knows though.

A lot of it though is going to be a matter of how you carefully build the scenes, and many times we're cheating sounds to create the desired effect.  I did a show a year ago which took place  everywhere on the streets of, and city landscape in, Bucharest Romania.  No option unfortunately for field recording, and not much of anything from Romania in the libraries if at all.  The source material I used ranged from Milan, Italy to Rio de Janeiro to NYC to London to Bulgaria to Greece.  The way it came together though sounded like "well, we're feeling the streets of Bucharest".  I certainly agree accurate and believable source is key and a big help.  But just a suggestion for consideration, try not to think too literal.